# Trouble referencing/populating a mongoose model in another model

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, mongoose-populate, mongoose-schema

Background: App that allows users to post voting polls.
I am having a little trouble populating my reference to my Polls model in the User model.  I am using mongoose.populate to try and populate the polls.  In my route, the populate function is not working correctly (the returned user is null). Here are my models...
users.js:

```
// models/users.js

var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Poll = require('./poll');

//define the schema for our user model
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    local:{
        email: String,
        password: String,
        name: String
    },
    twitter:{
        id: String,
        token: String,
        name: String
    },
    polls:[{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'Poll'}]
});
```

poll.js:

```
//load mongoose
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    User = require('./user');


var pollSchema = mongoose.Schema({
       name:String,
       options:[String],
       creator: {type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'User'}
});


module.exports = mongoose.model('Poll', pollSchema);
```

This is the route that I am going to implement the population in ...

```
 //require user and poll model 
 var User = require('../models/user'),
 Poll = require('../models/poll');

 app.post('/dashboard', isLoggedIn, function(req,res){ 

    var poll = {name: req.body.name, 
                options: req.body.option, 
                creator: req.user.local.id};

    //create new poll 
    var newPoll = new Poll();
    newPoll.polls = poll;

    //find the user with the request id and populate polls reference in User (UserSchema)
    User.findById(req.user.local.id)
         .populate('polls')
          .exec(function(err,user){ // cant figure this out...

              if(err){return err;}

              console.log(user); // yields null

              res.send({success:true, message: "Post Successful!"});

           });        
     });
```

Any help, advice, ideas would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Populations in Mongoose are such a great feature. From what I saw in your code, you don't seem to assign pools to users. You have the first part that references pools inside users but not the second part which references user inside pools and mongoose needs both to perform the operation.

I think you want pools to have a name and list of options. The one I can see in your code is a pool containing an array of pools so I changed the pool schema to fit your explanations.

Try to add a reference to the user in your pools with this new pool schema:

pools.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var pollSchema = mongoose.Schema({
       name:String,
       options:[String],
       creator: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }
});


module.exports = mongoose.model('Poll', pollSchema);
```

Now, when saving a pool, don't forget to add your user reference. You're populating pools on a user so the object passed in the mongoose callback will not be a list of pools but the user you want to find. Thanks to population, you'll get in the attribute `pools` a list of objects instead of a list of ids.

```
 var User = require('../models/user'),
 Poll = require('../models/poll');

 app.post('/dashboard', isLoggedIn, function(req,res){ 

    var poll = {
       name: req.body.name, 
       options: req.body.option, 
       creator: req.user.local.id
     };

    var newPoll = new Poll();
    newPoll.polls = poll;

    User.findById(req.user.local.id)
         .populate('polls')
          .exec(function(err, user){
           /*
             You should get in user object something like:
             {
               local: {...},
               twitter: {...},
               pools: [{
                 name: 'Pool1',
                 options: [...]
               }]
              }
           */
           });        
     });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for helping! Populate is definitely a powerful mongoose function; I'm still trying to wrap my head around it though.  I altered my code to follow what you posted, but the returned user object in the exec callback function is returning null for me.  I changed my code in the original post to reflect what I have now.

Comment: Turns out the user id was wrong (supposed to be req.user.local._id).  Everything worked smoothly after that.  Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 1):

In the code you have submitted, you are never explicitly creating a `User`.

There are two ways to handle what you want to do, one is better than the other and I will explain why.

You can add an array of Polls to your User model as such:

```
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    local:{
        email: String,
        password: String,
        name: String
    },
    twitter:{
        id: String,
        token: String,
        name: String
    },
    polls:[{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'Poll'}]
});
```

note that you should be specifying your `userSchema` = **new** mongoose.Schema.

If this is your choice, then when you create a new Poll instance, you have to create the Poll, retrieve the appropriate User (`User.findById`) and then push the Poll._id onto user.polls, and save the User.
This approach will allow you to simply call `.populate('polls')` on your user object when retrieving it to get all the user's polls in the result set.

Alternately, you can leave the polls array out of the User model, and simply create the reference in your Poll schema:

```
var pollSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
       name:String,
       options:[String],
       creator: {type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'User'}
});
```

again note you should be using **new** with your mongoose.Schema declaration.

If you take this approach, you simply need to add the user._id to the poll object when you create it.

You could then, if you wish, retrieve the User when you retrieve a Poll:

```
Poll.findById(...however you are retrieving your Poll id...)
         .populate('creator')
          .exec(function(err, poll){....
```

If you wanted to list all the polls posted by a given user, simply do something along the lines of:

```
Poll.find({"creator": req.params.userId})
    .populate('creator')
    .exec(function(err, poll) {
        if(err) return err;
        res.json(poll);
    };
```

the req.params.userId in the above code shouldn't be taken as a literal, and depends on how your app is retrieving the user id, likewise the response return approach is subject to your specific app, in the code above it is returning the array of polls that were created by the user as a json object.

The second approach is likely better for one reason, it avoids document bloat.
I don't seem to have enough of a reputation to either comment on or downgrade the previous answer, but in one serious regard it is incorrect.  **You absolutely do NOT have to have the array of polls in the User schema AND the user (creator) in the Polls schema for mongoose to resolve the populate call.**

Anytime you have an array referenced by a model schema that has no bounds (a user can create as many polls as they would like) you run the risk with a large system of each user document in your database becoming huge...for every poll a user creates, you are adding a new Poll document in the Polls collection, AND you are increasing the size of the parent User document.

You are essentially storing the same information twice..bad practice with any database.

If your parent object is limited to the number of children it can have, say a user is programmatically limited to creating 3 polls, then you are fine with adding the array to the User model.

If however there is no enforced limit to the growth of the children, say a user can create as many polls as they want, then I would suggest you do not have an array of polls in the User schema and instead have a creator in the Poll schema referencing the creating user.

In either case, do one or the other, and not both...in either case there is an effective way to get the data for the relationship without storing the relationship in two different documents.